# Why does C# let me overflow without any error or warning when casting an Int64 to an Int32 and how does it do the cast?

Tags: c#

This question stems from a bug where I iterated over a collection of `Int64` and accidentally did `foreach (int i in myCollection)`. I was trying to debug the baffling problem of how when I did a linq query, `i` was not part of the `myCollection`.

Here's some code that surprised me:

```
Int64 a = 12345678912345;

Console.Write((int)a);
```

I expected the compiler to give me an error. The usual one is that an implicit cast does not exist. But no, it didn't mind this at all. Not even a warning!

The outputted value of `(int)a` incidentally is `1942903641`.

I'm curious to know why the cast is permitted without any warnings and also how it comes up with that value. Any ideas?

Comment: "The usual one is that an implicit cast does not exist" - I've never seen that error message produced when your code contains an *explicit* cast.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2335112/961113) from Eric Lippert

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, C# does not check for overflows when processing numbers. This includes things like wrapping from `int.MaxValue` to `int.MinValue` in addition and multiplication, and when you cast `long`s to `int`s. To control this, use the [`checked` and `unchecked` keywords](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/khy08726.aspx), or the `/checked` compiler option.

The value `1942903641` is the result when your `long` is truncated to an `int`. It comes from the 32 least significant bits of the `long` value, taken as a [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) signed integer.

When using `foreach`, it's important to know that if you declare a type that doesn't match the type of the enumerable, it will treat it as if you casted to that type. `foreach (int i in myCollection)` compiles to something like `int i = (int)myEnumerator.Current;`, not `int i = myEnumerator.Current;`. You could use `foreach (var i in myCollection)` to avoid such mistakes in the future. `var` [is recommended](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ff926074.aspx) to use for the loop variable in `for` and `foreach` statements.

You can see the results of various things in the following example (hexadecimal output is used to show the truncation more clearly: they have the same ending digits, the `int` just lacks some of the more significant digits):

```
checked
{
    Int64 a = 12345678912345;
    Console.WriteLine(a.ToString("X"));
    Console.WriteLine((a % ((long)uint.MaxValue + 1L)).ToString("X"));
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine(((int)a).ToString("X")); // throws exception
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("It threw! " + e.Message);
    }
}
unchecked
{
    Int64 a = 12345678912345;
    Console.WriteLine(a.ToString("X"));
    Console.WriteLine((a % (long)Math.Pow(2, 32)).ToString("X"));
    Console.WriteLine(((int)a).ToString("X"));
}
```

This outputs:

```
B3A73CE5B59
73CE5B59
It threw! Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.
B3A73CE5B59
73CE5B59
73CE5B59
```

Comment: Great answer thanks. Do you know why it's disabled by default?

Comment: @SLC performance is probably the biggest reason. `checked` arithmetic is significantly slower than `unchecked`. Usually the behavior difference doesn't matter.

Comment: @SLC Probably for marketing reasons. See [Why don't languages raise errors on integer overflow by default?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/103654/why-dont-languages-raise-errors-on-integer-overflow-by-default)

Answer (score 15):

By default, conversions like this are not checked.  You'd have to ask for it explicitly:

```
   Console.Write(checked((int)a));    // Kaboom!
```

Checked conversions can be globally enabled by the C# compiler's [/checked option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/h25wtyxf.aspx).  That the project templates do not turn this option on for the Debug build is an oversight in my book, overflows can be drastically hard to diagnose.

Nothing you can't fix however, simply use Project > Properties > Build tab > Advanced button > tick the "Check for arithmetic overflow/underflow" option.  And note how your foreach loop now bombs with an OverflowException.  Do keep in mind that you'll be staring it at for a couple of minutes when it happens :)  It is not a very cheap check so you'll want to leave it off for the Release build.

Comment: I have got the following **working** statement: `foreach (SecuritySystemRoleEx role in userWithRoles.Roles)` where `userWithRoles.Roles` is a `IList<ISecurityRole>`. Therefore the right answer seems to be the one of @Damien_The_Unbeliever (believe it or not).

Comment: This Q+A is about numerical overflow checking, your foreach loop could not possible generate a OverflowException.

Comment: Yes, but the overflow checking comes into play because there is an invisible cast in the foreach loop. Otherwise you would get a compiler error (Cannot implicitly convert type). The OP says: "I expected the compiler to give me an error". At least we should get a compiler warning saying that the cast is possibly unintended.

Comment: And I described how you can get a diagnostic for it, you ought to try it.

Answer (score 3):

By default overflow checking is turned off for integral-type arithmetic operations.

You can enable it by putting your code into "checked" section:

```
        Int64 a = 12345678912345;
        checked
        {
            Console.Write((int)a);
        }
```

You can achieve the same thing by changing your compiler options.

Answer (score 1):

In modern versions of VS (since VS 2003 or so?) the arithmetic overflow/underflow check is turned off by default.
You can change this in project's properties -> build -> advanced -> "Check for arithmetic overflow/underflow".

Answer (score 1):

The reason the `foreach` hides that a cast occurs is because it originated in C# 1 - before generics.

It's defined as (Section 8.8.4 of the [C# language specification v5](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029)):

> A foreach statement of the form

```
foreach (V v in x) embedded-statement
```

> is then expanded to:

```
{
    E e = ((C)(x)).GetEnumerator();
    try {
        while (e.MoveNext()) {
            V v = (V)(T)e.Current;
            embedded-statement
        }
    }
    finally {
        … // Dispose e
    }
}
```

As you can see, the `foreach` automatically gains an explicit cast on that first line.

Answer (score 0):

Your value `12345678912345` gets truncated to a 32-bit integer. It's easier to understand in in hexadecimal:

- `12345678912345` in base 10 is `b3a73ce5b59` in hexadecimal.
- `b3a73ce5b59` truncated to 32 bits is `73ce5b59` (keep the least significant 8 hexadecimal digits).
- `73ce5b59` in hexadecimal is `1942903641` in base 10.

As to why you do not get any errors or warnings:

- Your conversion does not involve a compile-time constant, so the compiler will not do any static checks (in this simple case, it could, but not in general).
- By default, C#'s `long` to `int` explicit conversion generates the `conv.i4` CIL instruction, which truncates the value without throwing exceptions on overflow. Using a `checked` statement or expression, or compiling with the `/checked` switch will make the C# compiler emit the `conv.ovf.i4` instead, which does throw exceptions on overflow.